# NAudio - Record audio to memory, make changes to it, then save to disk

Tags: naudio

I would to do the following sequence:

1. Record audio using `WaveIn` into memory.
2. Get the content from memory as an Array of  IEEE 32-bit samples.
3. Make some modifications to the samples.
4. Save back to disk.

I know how to record using `WaveIn` and how to use `WaveFileReader` and `WaveFileWriter`. But there are other classes that are needed here which I don't know how to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Write all the audio you receive with `WaveIn` to a `MemoryStream`
2. When you've finished recording, reset the `MemoryStream.Position` to 0. Then pass that into a `RawSourceWaveStream` using the `WaveFormat` of your `WaveIn`
3. Use the `ToSampleProvider` on the `RawSourceWaveStream` to go to IEEE 32 bit
4. Read the audio a block at a time into a float[] from your sample provider.
5. Perform whatever DSP you need
6. Write that to a `WaveFileWriter`

If you implement your DSP as a custom `ISampleProvider` you can simplify your pipeline even more, and use `WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile` to automatically pull all the data through from the `MemoryStream` into your WAV file

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark. Just one question - When using `ISampleProvider.Read`, is there a reason to read a block at a time and not everything at once?

Comment: given that it's coming straight from a memory buffer, it's quite safe to read it all in one go. If you were pulling it through codecs etc, then reading in smaller blocks is usually advisable

Comment: I've just notice that I have a problem regarding the last step: I have a 'float[]', but I want to save the file as 16bit PCM with `WaveFileWriter.Write`

Comment: that's why I said to create an `ISampleProvider`. Then you could use `WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile16`, or pass it through a `SampleToWaveProvider16`